# Create a select tool in a website application like the one in OneDrive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i am making a web app some thing like oneDrive
now i want to add this select feature but i have no idea where to start or what to do

if anyone has an extension for that or a demo please show me i have been looking for 2 days and never found anything 
here is what i want :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OVNm.png)

Comment: What do u have on server side?

Comment: right now all i wrote is fron-end didn't start writing the back-end part

Answer (score 3):

Simply put this in a form

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

choose multiple files with ctrl and handle the request server-side

Answer (score 0):

Or, maybe you want something better than simple selecting tool. For example, **drop zone** that allow you to drag and drop **multiple files**. Just put it into your page.

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

If you want:

> ...drawn select - rectangle and put the selected items in an array

put this into your page:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object - here your Array

    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', f); // - here your file

        $.ajax({ // - here you can for example send your file with AJAX one by one
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_example_url",
            data: fd, // -this is your one file from array
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            }
        });

    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: YES I NEED THIS AS WELL. but also i need a select tool that selects all the items in the drawn select - rectangle and put the selected items in an array

Comment: I updated my answer. Here you can see how to work with files array.